# Redisson not supporting multiple shards in community version

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redisson

We are using redisson client for Redis.
But it doesn’t support multiple shards in community version . The support is there in pro version.

Now I am stuck as all the data is going to one shard ultimately causing memory issue.

Please suggest if Any workaround is there to support multiple shards in community version.